# Need to fail upstream project if downstream project fails on jenkins

Tags: jenkins, build, continuous-integration

I want upstream project to fail if downstream project fails. I am using Trigger Parameterized build on other projects option to trigger downstream project:

Image Link: 
[image]

As I checked answers of similar questions, it is suggested to check Block until triggered projects finish their builds /mark this build as failure ( But these options are not visible ) 
Please help

Answer (score 0):

> it is suggested to check Block until triggered projects finish their builds /mark this build as failure. But these options are not visible.

Make sure you have installed the [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin), which does have this option.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the build step **Trigger/call builds on other projects**  , and block it until the trigger job will finish

[image]